# How to connect Xiaomi 12 with Mac?

Tags: usb, usb-debugging, xiaomi, macos

I just recently bought a new Xiaomi 12 (MIUI 13.0.17 Global) and I cannot connect with USB to my Macbook Pro (OSX 12.1)

The issue starts with the prompt (selecting between MTP, File transfer, charging, etc) not even showing once I connect with USB, the cable should be fine, even an old PC recognizes it perfectly.
USB debugging is enabled. What am I missing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue, it was the adapter I was using with my Mac. Tried a different one and no problems after this.